# Undefined error in Laravel URL (404 not found)

Tags: vue.js, get, undefined, laravel-5.6

I'm starting with laravel and vue.js. The following code that I am going to show is copied from another code that I have written and it works correctly. I've been looking for days where the error is but I can not find anything. I need this to work in order to continue.

I apologize for the description of the problem but I am not sure how to ask it.

Im getting this error:

[image: Console error]

I am getting the results of the query correctly. The view loads correctly but does not show the array data.

I can even access other response data:

[image: response data]

The route:

```
Route::get('/oneminuteusers', 'OneMinuteUserController@index');
```

Component.vue:

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="user in usersArray" :key="user.id">
    <td v-text="user.user_name"></td>
    <td v-text="user.gender"></td>
    <td v-text="user.country"></td>
    <td v-text="user.games_played"></td>
    <td v-text="user.total_clicks"></td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>

        <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          username: "",
          country: "",
          gender: "",
          games_played: "",
          total_clicks: "",
          usersArray: [],
          totalUsers: "",
          criterio: "",
          buscar: ""
        };
      },
      computed: {

      },
      methods: {
        listUsers(buscar, criterio) {
          let me = this;
          var url = "/oneminuteusers?buscar=" +buscar +"&criterio=" +criterio;

          axios
            .get(url)
            .then(function(response) {
              var respuesta = response.data;
              me.usersArray = respuesta.users.data;
              me.totalUsers = respuesta.totalusers;
              console.log(me.totalUsers);
              console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        },
      },
      mounted() {
        this.listUsers(this.buscar, this.criterio);
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem can be raise for CROS.
the request need some headers for allow accessing cross-origin,
for solving the issue change your request as below:

```
var url = "/oneminuteusers";
data = {
    buscar: buscar
    criterio: criterio
}
header = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-CSRF-TOKEN, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
}

axios.get(url, data, header)
        .then(function(response) {
          var respuesta = response.data;
          me.usersArray = respuesta.users.data;
          me.totalUsers = respuesta.totalusers;
          console.log(me.totalUsers);
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

`